# SQLAlchemy memory hog on select statement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

As per the SQLAlchemy, select statements are treated as iterables in for loops.  The effect is that a select statement that would return a massive amount of rows does not use excessive memory.

I am finding that the following statement on a MySQL table:

```
for row in my_connections.execute(MyTable.__table__.select()):
    yield row
```

Does not seem to follow this, as I overflow available memory and begin thrashing before the first row is yielded.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The basic `MySQLdb` cursor fetches the entire query result at once from the server.
This can consume a lot of memory and time.
Use [MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) when you want to make a huge query and
pull results from the server one at a time.

Therefore, try passing `connect_args={'cursorclass': MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor}`
when creating the `engine`:

```
   from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
   import MySQLdb.cursors
   engine = create_engine('mysql://root:zenoss@localhost/e2', connect_args={'cursorclass': MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor})
   meta = MetaData(engine, reflect=True)
   conn = engine.connect()
   rs = s.execution_options(stream_results=True).execute()
```

See http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/ticket/1089

---

Note that using SSCursor locks the table until the fetch is complete. This affects other cursors using the same connection: Two cursors from the same connection can not read from the table concurrently.

However, cursors from different connections can read from the same table concurrently.

Here is some code demonstrating the problem:

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors as cursors
import threading
import logging
import config

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
query = 'SELECT * FROM huge_table LIMIT 200'

def oursql_conn():
    import oursql
    conn = oursql.connect(
        host=config.HOST, user=config.USER, passwd=config.PASS,
        db=config.MYDB)
    return conn

def mysqldb_conn():
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(
        host=config.HOST, user=config.USER,
        passwd=config.PASS, db=config.MYDB,
        cursorclass=cursors.SSCursor) 
    return conn

def two_cursors_one_conn():
    """Two SSCursors can not use one connection concurrently"""
    def worker(conn):
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        for row in cursor:
            logger.info(row)

    conn = mysqldb_conn()
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(conn, ))
               for n in range(2)]
    for t in threads:
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        # Second thread may hang or raise OperationalError:
        # File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 289, in _fetch_row
        #   return self._result.fetch_row(size, self._fetch_type)
        # OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

    for t in threads:
        t.join()

def two_cursors_two_conn():
    """Two SSCursors from independent connections can use the same table concurrently"""    
    def worker():
        conn = mysqldb_conn()        
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        for row in cursor:
            logger.info(row)

    threads = [threading.Thread(target=worker) for n in range(2)]
    for t in threads:
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='[%(asctime)s %(threadName)s] %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
two_cursors_one_conn()
two_cursors_two_conn()
```

Note that [oursql](http://pythonhosted.org/oursql/) is an alternative set of MySQL bindings for Python. oursql cursors are true server-side cursors which [fetch rows lazily by default](http://pythonhosted.org/oursql/tutorial.html#row-streaming-out). With `oursql` installed, if you change

```
conn = mysqldb_conn()
```

to

```
conn = oursql_conn()
```

then `two_cursors_one_conn()` runs without hanging or raising an exception.

Comment: This fixed my memory issues with MySQL and yield_per. Any idea why the reply on Trac says this is "nigh on useless"?

Comment: @bcoughlan: I've added some code and discussion of the limitation of using SSCursors concurrently.

Comment: This should solve for mysqldb, is there a similar option for mysqlconnector, as I am facing similar issue using that driver.

Comment: @YogeshSajanikar: I'm not that familiar with mysql-connector, but according to [this page](http://geert.vanderkelen.org/simulating-server-side-cursors-with-mysql-connectorpython/) there is not yet a server-side cursor in mysql-connector. The workaround is to fetch the data in chunks.