# Flask template streaming with Jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a flask application. On a particular view, I show a table with about 100k rows in total. It's understandably taking a long time for the page to load, and I'm looking for ways to improve it. So far I've determined I query the database and get a result fairly quickly. I think the problem lies in rendering the actual page. I've found [this page on streaming](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/) and am trying to work with that, but keep running into problems. I've tried the stream_template solution provided there with this code:

```
@app.route('/thing/matches', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@roles_accepted('admin', 'team')
def r_matches():
    matches = Match.query.filter(
            Match.name == g.name).order_by(Match.name).all()

    return Response(stream_template('/retailer/matches.html',
        dashboard_title = g.name,
        match_show_option = True,
        match_form = form,
        matches = matches))

def stream_template(template_name, **context):
    app.update_template_context(context)
    t = app.jinja_env.get_template(template_name)
    rv = t.stream(context)
    rv.enable_buffering(5)
    return rv
```

The Match query is the one that returns 100k+ items. However, whenever I run this the page just shows up blank with nothing there. I've also tried the solution with streaming the data to a json and loading it via ajax, but nothing seems to be in the json file either! Here's what that solution looks like:

```
@app.route('/large.json')
def generate_large_json():
    def generate():
        app.logger.info("Generating JSON")
        matches = Product.query.join(Category).filter(
            Product.retailer == g.retailer,
            Product.match != None).order_by(Product.name)
        for match in matches:
            yield json.dumps(match)
    app.logger.info("Sending file response")
    return Response(stream_with_context(generate()))
```

Another solution I was looking at was for pagination. This solution works well, except I need to be able to sort through the entire dataset by headers, and couldn't find a way to do that without rendering the whole dataset in the table then using JQuery for sorting/pagination.

The file I get by going to /large.json is always empty. Please help or recommend another way to display such a large data set!

Edit: I got the generate() part to work and updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in both cases is almost certainly that you are hanging on building 100K+ `Match` items and storing them in memory.  You will want to stream the results from the DB as well using [`yield_per`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.yield_per).  However, only PostGres+psycopg2 support the necessary [`stream_result`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execution_options.params.stream_results) argument ([here's a way to do it with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3699677/135978)):

```
matches = Match.query.filter(
        Match.name == g.name).order_by(Match.name).yield_per(10)
        # Stream ten results at a time
```

#### An alternative

If you are using Flask-SQLAlchemy you can make use of its [`Pagination` class](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.Pagination) to paginate your query server-side and not load all 100K+ entries into the browser.  This has the added advantage of not requiring the browser to manage all of the DOM entries (assuming you are doing the HTML streaming option).

#### See also

- [SQLAlchemy: Scan huge tables using ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1145941/135978)
- [How to Use SQLAlchemy Magic to Cut Peak Memory and Server Costs in Half](http://www.mobify.com/blog/sqlalchemy-memory-magic/)