# sqlalchemy cursor error during yield_per

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    main()
    for item in session.query(Item).yield_per(10):
    fetch = cursor.fetchmany(self._yield_per)
    self.cursor, self.context)
    l = self.process_rows(self._fetchmany_impl(size))
    row = self._fetchone_impl()
    self.__buffer_rows()
    self.__rowbuffer = collections.deque(self.cursor.fetchmany(size))
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) named cursor isn't valid anymore None None
```

I am suspect that calling session.commit() is interfering with .yield_per

```
sessionmaker_ = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker_)

def foo(item):
  # DO something to the item 
  session.add(item)
  session.commit()

def main():
  for item in session.query(Item).yield_per(5):
    foo(item)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try moving the .commit() after your for-loop like we suggested in #python?  Also, why did you edit your traceback like that?  Removing information is rarely helpful.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you haven't fetched all rows from a DBAPI cursor, then it's usually a bad idea to call commit() on that cursor's connection.  In this case psycopg2 (which I'm guessing that's the DBAPI you're on) is not able to maintain the state of a named cursor (which is what it uses when you want server-buffered rows) over the transaction.

One thing you should definitely change here is how frequently you're committing.  Ideally you wouldn't commit anything until your entire operation is complete.  The Session will automatically flush data as it needs to (well, if you turned on autoflush, which I'd recommend), or you can call flush() to force it, but this is independent of actually committing the transaction.  All those calls to commit() will make the operation much less efficient than it has to be, and of course it's getting in the way of the cursor for the other result set.   If you just put one commit() at the end of your loop, then you'd solve both issues at once.

If you still need to commit before the entire operation is finished, or even if not, I'd favor working in chunks rather than using yield_per(), which is quite brittle.  The recipe at http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/WindowedRangeQuery shows one way to do this.   DBAPI's are not well suited to dealing with extremely large result sets overall, even though psycopg2 gives us a little more leeway.

Answer (score 5):

Problem above can be solved via one more session

```
sessionmaker_ = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker_)
cool_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker_)

def foo(item):
   # DO something to the item 
   session.add(item)
   session.commit()

def main():
    for item in cool_session.query(Item).yield_per(5):
    item = session.merge(item, load=False)
    foo(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the cursor option "WITH HOLD", when it gets into an sqlalchemy release:
https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3667/support-postgresqls-with-hold-cursor

Note the caveat Scott mentions about Postgres materializing cursors on first commit.