# Improve query performance

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to read and join a lot of rows (~500k) from a PostgreSQL database and write them into a MySQL database.

My naive approach looks like this

```
    entrys = Entry.query.yield_per(500)

    for entry in entrys:
        for location in entry.locations:
            mysql_location = MySQLLocation(entry.url)
            mysql_location.id = location.id
            mysql_location.entry_id = entry.id

            [...]

            mysql_location.city = location.city.name
            mysql_location.county = location.county.name
            mysql_location.state = location.state.name
            mysql_location.country = location.country.name

            db.session.add(mysql_location)

    db.session.commit()
```

Every `Entry` has about 1 to 100 `Locations`.

This script is running now for about 20 hours and already consumes > 4GB of memory since everything in kept in memory till the session is committed.

With my try of committing earlier, I'm running into problems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233115/sqlalchemy-cursor-error-during-yield-per).

How do I improve the query performance? It needs to get a lot faster, since the amount of rows will grow to about 2500k over the next months.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use an [Extract, Transform, Load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) approach?

Comment: Basically `pg_dump dbname | mysql dbname`

Comment: @JochenRitzel, I'm joining multiple rows from multiple tables into one row for MySQL. I don't see how `pg_dump` could help.

Comment: Have you tried extracting data from Postgres into CSV and loading CSV into MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Your naive approach is flawed for the very reason that you already know - the stuff eating your memory are the model objects dangling in the memory waiting to be flushed to the mysql.

The easiest way would be to not use the ORM for conversion ops at all. Use the SQLAlchemy table objects directly, as they're also much faster.

Also, what you can do is create 2 sessions, and bind the 2 engines into separate sessions! Then you can commit the mysql session for each batch.

Comment: I support the option with 2 separate sessions, where one would clean them up with every batch using [expunge_all()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.expunge_all). In addition, the problems you (@dbanck) are running to are also answered using ranged query instead of yield_per.