# Looping through over 6k results, want to update a linked table, worried about time taken

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on a pre-existing application written in Python using Flask and SQLAlchemy (I did not create this application). I need to update just over 6k rows. A row from the main table (called SurveyRequest) has 3 foreign keys that point to a secondary table (AudioRecording). I need to go through each SurveyRequest row, then based on these 3 IDs, update the corresponding AudioRecording row.

I'm a bit confused about how session works in relation to SQLAlchemy.

I have my query set up to return the 6k results (I have no problem with that), its the loop that I need a bit of help with.

I'm going to be using this:

```
query = self.session.query(SurveyRequest).filter(
                SurveyRequest.audio_1 != None,
                SurveyRequest.audio_2 != None,
                SurveyRequest.audio_3 != None,
                SurveyRequest.sent_to_transcriber == None,
                SurveyRequest.created_at < before_date,
                SurveyRequest.participant_id >= 100000,
                SurveyRequest.participant_id < 300000,
                SurveyRequest.test_number == 1
            )

for sr in query.yield_per(100).enable_eagerloads(False):
```

I'm using yield as I don't want the system to load in all 6k results into memory (unless someone can suggest a better way?).

So for each SurveyRequest 'sr' row, I need to update the 3 linked AudioRecording rows. In SurveyRequest the 3 foreign keys are: audio_1, audio_2, audio_3. My idea is to pass each ID into a separate method that will then do the update I need to do to that specific AudioRecording. I have a feeling if I make the updates and commit, it will somehow disrupt the SurveyRequest query loop.

The way session is used in SQLAlchemy kinda confuses me. Can I do query loops and updates in the same session? Or do I need to make a separate session for the AudioRecording updates? Also is there a possible time out for processing 6k results?

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested to read this response about the state of your database cursor within a `yield_per()` block: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12233167/111033

Basically, you can't really commit until you're done buffering all the results - so you have to commit at the end of the loop.

`yield_per()` is very powerful and can solve a lot of memory management issues, however it's rather brittle and has some pretty big limitations, such as the one you discovered.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try the suggested code in that post. It might be the way for me to go